# jquery tabs - php function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have a website in development. After login the user is taken to a page w jq tabs.

The member page has pagination - there can be more than one page for the member to look at.

To deal w the brain-ache of pagination I dumped some of the code for the member page into a function w the tabs jQuery.

In Firefox, this all works.

In Chrome and Safari, the tabs are visible but the default first tab isn't selected. The corresponding 'pane' is hidden too. Think of a row of tabs without anything below them and none of the tabs selected.

The first tab should have the class 'current', and the pane should have the CSS attribute 'display:block' - exactly what Firefox supplies.

Why won't Chrome and Safari do the honourable thing ?

Any thoughts how to solve this problem without starting over would be gratefully received.

As an aside, in both Chrome and Safari the pagination still works. The next pages show fine. And returning to the first page shows the content and selected states as required.

thanks, Tom

[link text](http://pastie.org/1223286)

Comment: Please put some code in your question.

Comment: Fair enough - but there is a link at the bottom of my question. It shows code.  Tom